# Offline maps/GPS app for iOS

Tags: gratis, ios, offline, maps, gps

I am looking for a free iOS app that shows my GPS position.

As a background, it should show maps up to street level, for instance using locally downloaded OpenStreetMap data like [OsmAnd](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.osmand.plus) does.

Requirements:

- Works 100% offline (except the first time when downloading maps data)
- Free
- iOS
- Maps available for the whole world
- Bonus if I can pin places as "bookmarks"

Not needed: search, navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) actually has an [iOS version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id934850257) now.

- Works 100% offline (to the best of my knowledge)
- Free
- Supports all the maps OsmAnd for Android does (which is most of the world)
- Supports bookmarks
- Trip Recordiong
- Markers
- OpemStreetMap Editing
  And more!

The iOS version does not support navigation at this time.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mzstatic.com](http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/0f/dd/64/0fdd6401-6391-9ca1-961f-a891f714e8c5/screen322x572.jpeg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mzstatic.com](http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/bc/6d/ea/bc6deaea-d5ba-32d3-48e6-e57057b294a1/screen322x572.jpeg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Maps.Me](https://maps.me). It is available free of charge, for iOS or Android.

It uses data from OpenStreetMap. Maps are available for the whole world, you can download complete countries or regions to use offline.

It will use GPS to show your location on the map. You can add bookmarks for places of interest, and these bookmarks can be shared or imported/exported as KML files.

It also allows searching and basic routing to places. It all works offline.